# dynkin-diagrams package specifying properties of a node

Tags: diagrams, tikz-styles

When using the `dynkin-diagram` package is it possible to specify the style of the extended node? Consider for example the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\dynkin[edge length=1cm,
        edge/.style={thick},
        root radius=.1cm,
        */.style={
              ultra thick,
              fill=black!30!white,
              draw=black
            }] A{}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\dynkin[extended,
        edge length=1cm,
        edge/.style={thick},
        root radius=.1cm,
        */.style={
              ultra thick,
              fill=black!30!white,
              draw=black
            }] A{}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Can I edit the shape, color, etc. of the white node in the above example? I saw in the documentation the example

```
\dynkin[%
     edge length=.75cm,
     edge/.style={
           -{stealth[sep=1pt]}},
           labels={,1,2,\ell-1,\ell},
           labels*={0}] 
      A[1]{}
```

so there seems a way to excess the node, but I just don't understand how...

Comment: If you add `o/.style={fill=orange},` to the second diagram, the most negative root will be filled orange.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Nice, do you know how to do this for `\dynkin A[2]2` (i.e. just replace the above examples with this one)? I get an error message when trying to complie it with the option `o/.style={fill=orange}`. Also, mind sharing how you figured this out?

Comment: Please share with me the precise command that you try. `\dynkin[extended,
        edge length=1cm,
        edge/.style={thick},
        root radius=.1cm,
  o/.style={fill=orange},
        */.style={
              ultra thick,
              fill=black!30!white,
              draw=black
            }] A[2]{}` seems to work.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Your suggestion works as well for me, seems I confused some of the options. Feel free to convert your comment to an answer, so that I can mark it as solved!

Comment: I encourage you to use tikzset to set up global options for your Dynkin diagrams, to make your TeX code easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the style of the "empty" node by adjusting the `o` style. You may either completely overwrite the style with `o/.style={...}`, or just add some keys with `o/.append style={...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Out of the box:}
\begin{center}
\dynkin[extended,
        edge length=1cm,
        edge/.style={thick},
        root radius=.1cm,
        */.style={
              ultra thick,
              fill=black!30!white,
              draw=black
            }] A[2]{}
\end{center}

\paragraph{Use \texttt{o/.style=\{orange\}}:}
\begin{center}
\dynkin[extended,
        edge length=1cm,
        edge/.style={thick},
        root radius=.1cm,
        o/.style={fill=orange},
        */.style={
              ultra thick,
              fill=black!30!white,
              draw=black
            }] A[2]{}
\end{center}

\paragraph{Use \texttt{o/.append style=\{orange\}}:}
\begin{center}
\dynkin[extended,
        edge length=1cm,
        edge/.style={thick},
        root radius=.1cm,
        o/.append style={fill=orange},
        */.style={
              ultra thick,
              fill=black!30!white,
              draw=black
            }] A[2]{}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]